# Rewrite rule for subdomain, nice URL variable and slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I struggle with setting up proper mod_rewrite rule for my domain. 
I was never any good at regexp-kinda expressions, but every documented tutorial I just fail to use for myself.

**Domain:** example.org

My current rule is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?page=$1
```

which kinda work (as I can get 'name' variable from striping the slash out of page. But I'm sure there's more nice and edge-cut way of doing this.

**Desired mod_rewrite behavior:**

- **example.org** -> index.php?**sub=*(empty)***
- **subdomain**.example.org -> index.php?sub=**subdomain**
- subdomain.example.org/**something** -> index.php?sub=subdomain&**page=something**
- subdomain.example.org/**something/** -> index.php?sub=subdomain&**page=something**
- subdomain.example.org/something/**extra** -> index.php?sub=subdomain&page=something**&name=extra**
- subdomain.example.org/something/**extra/** -> index.php?sub=subdomain&page=something**&name=extra**
- www excluded from URL (www.subdomain -> subdomain)

(notice the slashes)

As the "subdomain" part is a wildcard on server (*.example.org) I'd also like to exclude some names from the rule.
In example: "content.example.org" should not be rewritten, but should refer to normal folder.

Could anyone help me out with the rule code, please? :-)

Regards,
Andrew